# how many entries in my Translation Lookaside Buffer (TLB)

Tags: operating-system, kernel, intel, tlb

I want to know how many entries my TLB has. Based on that, I could find out the total amount of memory can be referred by my TLB. I am using CentOS 7 and Intel core i7 processor.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/113585/23529 is my first result on Google.

Comment: I am using CentOS 7 and there is no such command on my OS.

Comment: Then either see if you can install it using your package manager or install it from source available at www.etallen.com/cpuid.html ..?

Comment: number of physical cores * number of 1GiB hugepages per core is approximately the number you want.  Most CPUs have separate TLB space for hugepages vs. normal pages, but the normal pages can only map a trivial amount compared to 1G hugepages.  (Although it's much easier to use 2M hugepages than 1G.)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is available:

```
Available Packages
Name        : cpuid
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 20170122
Release     : 6.el7
Size        : 89 k
Repo        : base/7/x86_64
Summary     : Dumps information about the CPU(s)
URL         : http://www.etallen.com/cpuid.html
Licence     : GPLv2+
Description : cpuid dumps detailed information about x86 CPU(s) gathered from the CPUID
            : instruction, and also determines the exact model of CPU(s). It supports Intel,
            : AMD, and VIA CPUs, as well as older Transmeta, Cyrix, UMC, NexGen, and Rise
            : CPUs.
```